# StoreKit for VOIP apps

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip, pushkit

As apple has removed VOIP background mode for the iOS apps. It seems mandatory to use PushKit to make the app working on VOIP background mode. Is there any way to make voip background mode working without changing or adding any script at server side? Please suggest me any possible way.

Comment: Much confusing, give us some example, what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want my VOIP app to be working on background mode without making any changes at server side. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: If your VOIP app is live on app store, then nothing to do for change, it will work.

Comment: No It is not still live. Development is on progress.

Comment: If you have configured VOIP properly then it will work, check this things to make sure your VOIP is perfectly configured or not https://zeropush.com/guide/guide-to-pushkit-and-voip and https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Comment: Here there is a .php file that we need to configure at server side. Without this can we use Pushkit?

Comment: Yes, you have to configure that.

Comment: Ohh. Is there any other way to make VOIP background enable without changing at server side? Any other way other then pushkit?

Comment: .php file is used for sending VOIP ( Pushkit ) payload like APNS, if you dont have that then how will you get payload on device and your local notification will work? so it is required.

Comment: Check my answer this way you have to configure whole VOIP things. let me know if any query.

Comment: Does it worked?

Answer (score 0):

One you receive silent push notification payload, then you have to schedule local notification because silent push notification does not come in notification center. upto your local notification sound file plays ( Max 30 seconds ) your application will be invoke in background or kill state. you can do require activity here but not UI activity.

While tapping on interactive local notification you can do further UI activity.

Use below structure to achieve your task.

Use this simplepush.php file

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):

    
      $deviceToken = '1234567890123456789';
//

    
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'ProjectName';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PemFileName.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
//  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body

$body['aps'] = array(
                     'content-available'=> 1,
                     'alert' => $message,
                     'sound' => 'default',
                     'badge' => 0,
                     );

    

// Encode the payload as JSON
    
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Use below commands to create pem file and use it in above code

```
$ openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out PushCert.pem

# Convert .p12 to .pem. Enter your pass pharse which is the same pwd that you have given while creating the .p12 certificate. PEM pass phrase also same as .p12 cert.  
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey1.pem -in pushkey.p12

Enter Import Password:

MAC verified OK

Enter PEM pass phrase:

Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:

# To remove passpharse for the key to access globally. This only solved my stream_socket_client() & certificate capath warnings.
$ openssl rsa -in PushKey1.pem -out PushKey1_Rmv.pem

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey1.pem:

writing RSA key

# To join the two .pem file into one file:
$ cat PushCert.pem PushKey1_Rmv.pem > ApnsDev.pem
```

After that go to simplepush.php location and fire command -> php simplepush.php

This way you can test your push kit notification setup architecture.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

[Download](https://drive.google.com/a/brainvire.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKaGxGZVV4X0Y0d3M/view)

```
import UIKit
import PushKit


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate{



func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)

    self. PushKitRegistration()

    return true
}



//MARK: - PushKitRegistration

func PushKitRegistration()
{

    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

        let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

        // Set the registry's delegate to self

        voipRegistry.delegate = self

        // Set the push type to VoIP

        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

    let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
        count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

    print(hexString)


}


@available(iOS 8.0, *)
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
    // Process the received push
    // From here you have to schedule your local notification

}

}
```

[image]

[image]

In parallel if you setup Socket architecture. Then Socket used to broadcast data for example which users are online / offline and you need to know without calling an API then you can use socket, socket architecture on server will send data on online / offline user to devices without making request from device.